# Different arrays contain the elements of the first array

Tags: php, arrays

#### Background

I have two arrays named `$attributes` and `$graphs`. Attributes holds data as follows:

`$attributes     = array('lat', 'long', '');`

Whereas, `$graphs` contains sub-arrays as such:

```php
$graphs = array(
    'bar_chart'  => array('gender', `lat`, `long`),
    'pie_chart'  => array('gender', 'location', 'pos_sentiment', 'neg_sentiment'),
    'line_chart' => array('pos_sentiment', 'neg_sentiment')
);
```

#### The problem

My `$attributes` array is generated from data in my database, and if one of the elements is empty the graph that contains the other attributes is not returned, which I desire.

#### My question

I want to know if the first array (`attributes`) has any elements in the second array (`graphs`). I don't want empty strings being considered.

#### Update

Having realised that the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function removed empty strings I applied it to my own code above and got the result I desired.

The code was:

```php
    foreach ($graphs as $key => $array)
    {
        if (count(array_intersect(array_filter($attributes), $array)) == count(array_filter($attributes)))
        {
            $solved[] = $key;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

People:

```
Array
  (
   [0] => 3
   [1] => 20
  )
```

Wanted Criminals:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => 4
[2] => 8
[3] => 11
[4] => 12
[5] => 13
[6] => 14
[7] => 15
[8] => 16
[9] => 17
[10] => 18
[11] => 19
[12] => 20
)
```

You can use `array_intersect().`

```
$result = !empty(array_intersect($people, $criminals));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$attributes = array('lat', 'long', '');

$graphs = array(
    'bar_chart'  => array('gender', 'lat', 'long'),
    'pie_chart'  => array('gender', 'location', 'pos_sentiment', 'neg_sentiment'),
    'line_chart' => array('pos_sentiment', 'neg_sentiment')
);

$res  = array();
foreach($graphs as $key=>$val){
    $res[$key]   = array_intersect($attributes, $val);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Output :

Ar

```
ray
(
    [bar_chart] => Array
        (
            [0] => lat
            [1] => long
        )

    [pie_chart] => Array
        (
        )

    [line_chart] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Here `$res` is a array which contains, the attributes present in `$grahp` with key, if not present it will be null.